# How to automate graph axis labeling with plotmath expressions?

Tags: r, label, plotmath

I am trying to create multiple graphs with `ggplot2` through using multiple instances of its plotting function and assign proper y-axis labels (with plotmath) to each function. Below is some code that demonstrates my failed solution. (mind the silliness)

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  measure = c('Current', 'Resistance', 'Volts'),
  mean = c(532, 42, 50),
  sd = c(45, 6, 8),
  ylabel = c('Amps (A)', 'Ohms (Omega)', 'Volts (V)')
)

for (i in 1:3)) {
  g <- ggplot(df[i,], aes(x = measure, y = mean)) + 
    geom_point(size = 7) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = mean + sd, ymin = mean - sd), width = .25) +
    ylab(expression(df[i,]$ylabel))

  ggsave(g, paste0('~/Desktop/', df$measure[i]))

}
```

I am running into a problem with `expression()` and its placing of special characters. How would you get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `parse` instead of `expression`:

```
ylab(parse(text = df[i, ]$ylabel))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! However, it removes the spacing between, for example, "Ohms" and "Omega". Is there a way to keep the spacing?

Comment: Oh right I didn't see it. You can try replacing `"Ohms (Omega)"` with `"Ohms~ ~(Omega)"`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!