# Base R graphics making X-Axis in pi units

Tags: r, plot, label

I am trying to make my x-axis ticks in pi units, but it is not working how I thought it would.  Here is an example of my problem.  No libraries required.

```
 curve(sin(x), from = -2*pi*3, to = 2*pi*3, xaxt='n' )
 axis(1, at= seq(-2*pi*3, 2*pi*3, by = 2*pi), 
      labels=expression(paste(seq(-2*3, 2*3, by = 2), pi, sep = "")))
```

Here is the error message I am receiving

***Error in axis(1, at = seq(-2 * pi * 3, 2 * pi * 3, by = 2 * pi), labels = expression(paste(seq(-2 *  :
'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 7 != 1***

I think that the `expression()` function might just not work inside the `axis()` function?  But that seems unlikely because it works for axis labels and plot titles.

The answer to this question is similar to [How to automate graph axis labeling with plotmath expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998260/how-to-automate-graph-axis-labeling-with-plotmath-expressions), but differs in that this is for Base R (not ggplot), and this is about greek letters not automation.

Comment: `axis(1, at=seq(-6,6,by=2)*pi, labels=parse(text=paste0(seq(-6,6,by=2), "*pi")))`

Comment: If the dupe-link and my comment don't resolve your issue kpr62, my apologies for misinterpreting your question. Feel free to @-ping me and we can talk through further resolution. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, thank you! It is resolved.